# Set AD attribute with input from other attribute in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes

sorry the title is horrid.  Basically, all users have an attribute titled 'manager'.  It is formatted thus.

```
 CN=First Last,OU=IT,DC=Domain,DC=com
```

What I'd like to do is, using a script, grab that user's sAMAccountName and assign it to another attribute, based on that 'manager' field alone.  I'm a beginner with powershell, but it's what I've been tasked to do by my boss so here I am.

EDIT: Ultimately the goal is to do this to the entire corporation, but I figured I'd just start here.

Comment: Do you plan to change the users manager or you are going to change something like a custom attribute based on who the manager is? The ladder would work well with a switch. I know the former is covered  here in SO already somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, using the manager field, grab that manager's account name and assign it to one of the  user's custom attributes.  I couldn't find much, but I didn't know how to word it.  Any tips there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to give a little more information but as your question stands this would work.

```powershell
$user = "user"
$manager = Get-Aduser $user -Properties manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manager
Switch -wildcard ($manager){
    "*Manager Name*"{Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{extensionAttribute4="Bagelphobia"} -WhatIf}
}
```

You should have no issue adapting this with a `ForEach-Object` loop if you had an input file.

We get a `$user` manager then we set the same users `extensionAttribute4` if there manager name* matches "Manager Name".

*Note*: In the simple way I am trying to show you it is possible for this string to have unwanted matches. For instance, if the managers had similar names the order of your switch clauses would important. Test accordingly. I added `-WhatIf` to help you with your testing. Remove it when the code is ready.